# setResponsePage() and setRequestTarget() in wicket 6.x or 7.x

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5, wicket-6, wicket-1.6, wicket-7

I had code like below

```
1)
getRequestCycle().setRedirect(true);
setResponsePage(ClasAdminHome.class); Repalced with
```

I converted to latest version as below, no compilation error

```
RequestCycle.get().scheduleRequestHandlerAfterCurrent(new RenderPageRequestHandler(new PageProvider(ClasAdminHome.class), RenderPageRequestHandler.RedirectPolicy.ALWAYS_REDIRECT));
```

The same thing I tried for below code But am not getting the solution,

```
2)
getRequestCycle().setRedirect(true);
getRequestCycle().setRequestTarget(new RedirectRequestTarget(redirectUrl));
```

How can I upgrade it? is it first code I have written  correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not  quit getting yours  `getRequestCycle().setRequestTarget` deprecated in wicket 5.You can replace simply with below code .

Wicket 6 or 7 You can try like this.

```
getRequestCycle().scheduleRequestHandlerAfterCurrent(new RedirectRequestHandler(redirectUrl));
```

For more info check here wicket upgrading [docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Migration+to+Wicket+1.5)

Comment: you mean no need to convert getRequestCycle().setRedirect(true);
only the code what you have given will work

Comment: Thanks, what about code 1) is it correct? what I have written?

Comment: Yes That no issue . FYI remove `setRedirect(true)`wherever is there.You dont need it.

Comment: I used RenderPageRequestHandler.RedirectPolicy.ALWAYS_REDIRECT) for that, is it ok?

Comment: I think it more complex code `setResponsePage(ClasAdminHome.class` this alone enough to redirect the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147799/discussion-between-soorapadman-and-s-p-roopesh).

Comment: Ok i will try. :)

Comment: Another simple way to redirect is to use the [RestartResponseException](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/7.x/org/apache/wicket/RestartResponseException.html).

Comment: Hi Soorapadman, do you have any solution for this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44963393/deployed-web-application-jdk-1-6-wicket-1-4-9-in-jboss-eap-7-0-getting-wicke